# Box shadow inside box

Tags: html, css

I want to set box shadow inside a box or div but only at right and left sides.
I want something like this below. Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To get it to appear only on the sides you need to essentially have two different sets:

`box-shadow:inset 5px 0 8px -5px #000,inset -5px 0 8px -5px #000;`

Answer (score 3):

You can create one inner div and one outer div. Then you need to set the shadow separately for both divs.

```css
.outer, .inner {
 width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inlin-block;
}

.outer {
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 23px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 23px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 23px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.inner {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset -10px 0px 23px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset -10px 0px 23px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: inset -10px 0px 23px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Or you can use also one div, with 2 inset parameters:

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inlin-block;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 23px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), inset -10px 0px 23px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 23px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), inset -10px 0px 23px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: inset 5px 0 8px -5px #000,inset -5px 0 8px -5px #000, inset -10px 0px 23px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you..That is helpful Gabriel

Answer (score 1):

And what about a linear-gradeint solution:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:
  linear-gradient(to left,#ccc , transparent 20%),
  linear-gradient(to right,#ccc , transparent 20%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the two div's. check the below code. 
But it will great if you can use the background image.

```
<div class="div1">
   <div class="div2"><div>
 <div>

.div1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #c51e1e;
    margin: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.div2 {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 27px 17px #d6cdcd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with html:

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

and css:

```
#box {
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#box:before {
  content: "";
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 10px #888888;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
}
#box:after {
  content: "";
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 10px #888888;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0;
}
```